# My leopard gecko is sick

Tags: health, reptiles, eating, leopard-geckos, weight

My leopard gecko got moved to a new cage a month ago. In the last two weeks he has refused to eat anything. He is out of hiding and walking throughout his cage. His tank is around 84°F (29°C) on the hot side. He has heat from above and below. He is also three years old. He has lost weight, but is not super skinny. In the last three days he has started to gag. He also makes noises that he has never made before. He is not lethargic. I am worried that he refuses to eat and he is gagging more as days progress. I am working on taking him to the vet, but it is hard due to location and work it is hard. Any thoughts if this is an emergency? What could it possibly be?

Answer (score 0):

He sure is depressed about the new cage, and much more if it is very different from the previous one. If you can, change it back to the old cage, and only put it in the new one sometimes, longer and longer so that it is a transition and not a drastic change.